# How to save hard disk data

Tags: 18.04

I can share my damaged Ubuntu hard disk data with cable on other Ubuntu laptop, if I can then how? Please healp me

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the versions of Ubuntu you are running as well as how badly broken the damaged system is? This might make it easier to explain how to share folders over a network 

Comment: Both system is same versions 18.04

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if this could help you, but I think that the easiest way to do this is to prepare a USB Stick with the Ubuntu installer like described here: https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu, then boot from it selecting the "Try ubuntu" option. With this you will have a live desktop that can access the disks.

After that, you can save your data in the persistance space of the USB stick or upload to your cloud o some web storage service (like Dropbox or Wetransfer) to retrieve it later.

I used this method to recover the system if it has booting problems, and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

If I didn't understand wrong, you need to access your files by plugging into another device.

Plug your drive boot into Ubuntu, find your device from `Disks` application click it, select the partition in `Volumes` section, click to `Play` button, It should appear in your File Manager.

Here I got a screenshoot for you:

[image: Gnome Disks]

Alternatively you can do it from your terminal:

- Find your device after typing this: (In my case it's /dev/sdb2)

```
$ sudo lsblk
```

[image: lsblk]

- Mount it:

```
$ sudo mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt
```

You can now access to your disk by going to `/mnt` directory (`Other locations` -> `Computer` -> `/mnt` in Nautilus).

- You can unmount your drive by typing this to your terminal:

```
$ sudo umount /mnt
```

**Note:** If this is not related to your question (since it is little hard to understand), please edit your question I will try to edit my answer as well.